# Python: Strip double quotes and multiple extra delimiter only for the last row in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

Requirement: To remove double quotes and extra delimiter only for the last row in the file in S3

**File in S3:**

```
"MT"|"Montana"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"NV"|"Nevada"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"CA"|"California"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"NJ"|"New Jersey"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"TR"|"4"||||
```

**Expected Output file in S3**

```
"MT"|"Montana"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"NV"|"Nevada"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"CA"|"California"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
"NJ"|"New Jersey"|"2018-01-16"|"N"
TR|4
```

Here the thing is some file can have more columns and hence more like `"TR"|"4"|||||`.  And I need output as `TR|4`

I have tried below in local ...

Also below it removes only `"` but not all the trailing `|`

[image]

```py
    file = "/Downloads/file.txt"
    lines = open(file, 'r').readlines()
    new_last_line = (lines[-1].strip('|'))
    new_last_line = new_last_line.replace('"', '')
    lines[-1] = new_last_line
    open(file, 'w').writelines(lines)
```

> ***EDIT: Solution***: I have achieved as below

```py
    file = "/Downloads/file.txt"
    lines = open(file, 'r').readlines()
    lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip()
    fields = [field.replace('"', '') for field in lines[-1].split('|') if field]
    lines[-1] = '|'.join(fields)
    open(file, 'w').writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried out .. but I want the output to be `TR|4` NOT `TR|4|`

Comment: I have updated the original question to make it more clear, apologize . `Here the thing is some file can have more columns and hence more like "TR"|"4"|||||. And I need output as TR|4`

Comment: See [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/CylindricalDefenselessTexts#main.py) removes all trailing `|` independent from how much exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some ugly code that does what you need. It takes your first example as an input and gives your wanted output.

```
last_line = str.split('\n')[-1].replace('|', '').split('"')
str = str.split('\n')
del str[-1]
last_line[1] = last_line[1] + '|'
str.append(''.join(last_line))
str = '\n'.join(str)
```

Also, `str` variable contains your input that you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code as below and is not removing the last row extra delimiters `|`

Expected output `TR|4826301` in the last row

```py
with open(input, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file, open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
            lines = input_file.readlines()
            lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip()
            fields = [field.replace('"', '') for field in lines[-1].split('|') if field]
            lines[-1] = '|'.join(fields)

            # now write the modified list back out to the file
            output_file.writelines(lines)
            input_file.close()
            output_file.close()
```

Output as below

[image]